# Text wrapping under IMG vertical-align:middle not working

Tags: html, css

I am getting unexpected results when using vertical-align on an image with accompanying text. If the text is wider than the container, it wraps UNDER the image like this, instead of simply wrapping to the next line:

[alt text http://preview.moveable.com/jm/verticalalign.png](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/verticalalign.png)

My HTML is simple:

```
<ul>
   <li><img .../> some text </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

- I have a height and `overflow-y:scroll` on the `UL` (likely not relevant)
- I have a height set on the `LI` that is large enough for the placeholder image plus spacing.
- I have `vertical-align:middle` on the image to get the text in the right place, almost
- The rest is just margins and borders
- Am am NOT using floats

How can I get the text to wrap properly, perferably without more markup?

Comment: You say that you are setting vertical align on the image; is it on the image only, or on both the image and the text?

Comment: It is only on the image.

Comment: "How can I get the text to wrap properly"

Define 'properly'.

Comment: I think the post in quite self-explanatory: "it wraps UNDER the image like this, instead of simply wrapping to the next line"

Comment: I think @graphicdivine was wondering what should happen if the height of text exceeds the height of the image.

Comment: Vertical-align:middle is not "not working".  It works fine.  An inline image, vertical-aligned middle behaves like this: inline, ie as if it were part of the line of text.  What you are after is a block level, wrapping behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is static i would use a background image on the li and then simply add left padding to allow for the correct spacing

```
  li {
      background: url(/images/foo.jpg) center left no-repeat;
      padding-left: barpx;
  }
```

you could also use a margin on the li to allow for spacing to the left of the image inside the ul

if the images are different i would simply apply a class to each li to distinguish the difference

**edit for seo friendlyness:**

add the images into the markup and then hide them with your stylesheet so the user only sees the image set with background image, Google bots ignore stylesheets so will be served the image in the markup.

```
  li img {
     display:none
  }
```

Comment: to keep it seo friendly you could add the images in and within the css declare

li img {
  display:none;
} 

so that the user only sees the background image but googlebots get the actual image

Answer (score 1):

As @graphicdivine pointed out, there are two ways to interpret "properly."  If you want things to fill up all the space around the image, I would do what he suggested: use `float: left;` on the image.

If, instead, you wanted to have a vertical block of text next to the image, you could apply the following:

```
<li style="display: table-row;">
<img src="..." style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;" />
<span style="display: table-cell;">...</span>
</li>
```

Same disclaimer as before, though: this is no good in IE.  Also, it breaks your "no more markup" rule, though I'm not sure how you wanted to achieve a different result without making changes.  Perhaps I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: If you float the image, you lose the ability to use vertical alignment. I think I may just have to use......a table! (no, no! run away!)

Comment: `display: table-cell` has no effect on `img` unless you put it inside a `div`, then it works: `<div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;"><img src="..." /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could float the image left.

Comment: I was thinking of going with this too.  I got the feeling the OP didn't want to use floats, though.